# Regexp test in Fluentular passed but pattern not matched when use Fluentd to get logs

Tags: regex, fluentd

When I test regexp in Fluentular, response is in the form of json
This is my regexp:

```
/^((?<time>([0-9]{4})-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1]) [0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2},[0-9]{3})\s)(?<level>[^ ]*)\s+(?<package>[^ ]*)\s+\[(?<thread>[^\]]*)\]\s+(?<message>(.|\s)+)$/m
```

This is test string (Logs of Java Spring boot include Exception)

```
2022-10-06 02:34:42,784 ERROR com.ftl.common.handlers.BaseRequestHandler [Thread-4] exception while handling message
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.util.ArrayList<com.jbsv.community.model.integration.navibridge.response.StockListRes>` from Object value (token `JsonToken.START_OBJECT`)
 at [Source: UNKNOWN; byte offset: #UNKNOWN]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._convert(ObjectMapper.java:4393)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.convertValue(ObjectMapper.java:4334)
    at com.jbsv.community.handler.kafka.RequestSender.sendKafka(RequestSender.java:62)
    at com.jbsv.community.service.integration.NaviBridgeService.getStockList(NaviBridgeService.java:24)
    at com.jbsv.community.service.query.StockListQueryService.getStockList(StockListQueryService.java:35)
    at com.jbsv.community.handler.kafka.RequestHandler.handle(RequestHandler.java:276)
    at com.ftl.common.handlers.BaseRequestHandler.process(BaseRequestHandler.java:80)
    at com.ftl.common.handlers.BaseRequestHandler.process(BaseRequestHandler.java:64)
    at com.ftl.common.kafka.KafkaRequestHandler.access$001(KafkaRequestHandler.java:16)
    at com.ftl.common.kafka.KafkaRequestHandler.lambda$init$1(KafkaRequestHandler.java:96)
    at com.ftl.common.kafka.ThreadedKafkaConsumer$HandleWorker.run(ThreadedKafkaConsumer.java:91)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

This is response in Fluentular:

```
"level":"ERROR",
"package":"com.ftl.common.handlers.BaseRequestHandler",
"thread":"Thread-4",
"message":"exception while handling message java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.util.ArrayList<com.jbsv.community.model.integration.navibridge.response.StockListRes>` from Object value (token `JsonToken.START_OBJECT`) at [Source: UNKNOWN; byte offset: #UNKNOWN] at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._convert(ObjectMapper.java:4393) at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.convertValue(ObjectMapper.java:4334) at com.jbsv.community.handler.kafka.RequestSender.sendKafka(RequestSender.java:62) at com.jbsv.community.service.integration.NaviBridgeService.getStockList(NaviBridgeService.java:24) at com.jbsv.community.service.query.StockListQueryService.getStockList(StockListQueryService.java:35) at com.jbsv.community.handler.kafka.RequestHandler.handle(RequestHandler.java:276) at com.ftl.common.handlers.BaseRequestHandler.process(BaseRequestHandler.java:80) at com.ftl.common.handlers.BaseRequestHandler.process(BaseRequestHandler.java:64) at com.ftl.common.kafka.KafkaRequestHandler.access$001(KafkaRequestHandler.java:16) at com.ftl.common.kafka.KafkaRequestHandler.lambda$init$1(KafkaRequestHandler.java:96) at com.ftl.common.kafka.ThreadedKafkaConsumer$HandleWorker.run(ThreadedKafkaConsumer.java:91) at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)"
```

But when I use Fluentd with td-agent.conf:

```
<source>
  @type tail
  path /home/huy/Documents/jbsv-logs/event.log
  pos_file /home/huy/Documents/jbsv-logs/event.log.pos
  tag log.log
  <parse>
    @type regexp
    expression /^((?<time>([0-9]{4})-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1]) [0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2},[0-9]{3})\s)(?<level>[^ ]*)\s+(?<package>[^ ]*)\s+\[(?<thread>[^\]]*)\]\s+(?<message>(.|\s)+)$/m
  </parse>
</source>

<match *.**>
  @type stdout
</match>
```

I can get response type json for first line include timestamp, level,..that i defined. But from the 2nd line, after Enter, logs display: fluent.warn: {"message":"pattern not matched: "...}

Logs in td-agent.log:

```
2022-10-07 16:30:58 +0700 [info]: parsing config file is succeeded path="/etc/td-agent/td-agent.conf"
2022-10-07 16:30:58 +0700 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-calyptia-monitoring' version '0.1.3'
2022-10-07 16:30:58 +0700 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-concat' version '2.5.0'
2022-10-07 16:30:58 +0700 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-elasticsearch' version '5.2.3'
2022-10-07 16:30:58 +0700 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-flowcounter-simple' version '0.1.0'
2022-10-07 16:30:58 +0700 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-kafka' version '0.18.1'
2022-10-07 16:30:58 +0700 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-metrics-cmetrics' version '0.1.2'
2022-10-07 16:30:58 +0700 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-opensearch' version '1.0.7'
2022-10-07 16:30:58 +0700 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-prometheus' version '2.0.3'
2022-10-07 16:30:58 +0700 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-prometheus_pushgateway' version '0.1.0'
2022-10-07 16:30:58 +0700 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-record-modifier' version '2.1.0'
2022-10-07 16:30:58 +0700 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-rewrite-tag-filter' version '2.4.0'
2022-10-07 16:30:58 +0700 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-s3' version '1.7.1'
2022-10-07 16:30:58 +0700 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-sd-dns' version '0.1.0'
2022-10-07 16:30:58 +0700 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-systemd' version '1.0.5'
2022-10-07 16:30:58 +0700 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-td' version '1.2.0'
2022-10-07 16:30:58 +0700 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-utmpx' version '0.5.0'
2022-10-07 16:30:58 +0700 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-webhdfs' version '1.5.0'
2022-10-07 16:30:58 +0700 [info]: gem 'fluentd' version '1.15.2'
2022-10-07 16:30:58 +0700 [warn]: define <match fluent.**> to capture fluentd logs in top level is deprecated. Use <label @FLUENT_LOG> instead
2022-10-07 16:30:58 +0700 [info]: using configuration file: <ROOT>
  <source>
    @type tail
    path "/home/huy/Documents/jbsv-logs/event.log"
    pos_file "/home/huy/Documents/jbsv-logs/event.log.pos"
    tag "log.log"
    <parse>
      @type "regexp"
      expression /^((?<time>([0-9]{4})-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1]) [0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2},[0-9]{3})\s)(?<level>[^ ]*)\s+(?<package>[^ ]*)\s+\[(?<thread>[^\]]*)\]\s+(?<message>(.|\s)+)$/gm
      unmatched_lines 
    </parse>
  </source>
  <match *.**>
    @type stdout
  </match>
</ROOT>
2022-10-07 16:30:58 +0700 [info]: starting fluentd-1.15.2 pid=1026737 ruby="2.7.6"
2022-10-07 16:30:58 +0700 [info]: spawn command to main:  cmdline=["/opt/td-agent/bin/ruby", "-Eascii-8bit:ascii-8bit", "/opt/td-agent/bin/fluentd", "--log", "/var/log/td-agent/td-agent.log", "--daemon", "/var/run/td-agent/td-agent.pid", "--under-supervisor"]
2022-10-07 16:30:58 +0700 [info]: adding match pattern="*.**" type="stdout"
2022-10-07 16:30:58 +0700 [info]: adding source type="tail"
2022-10-07 16:30:58 +0700 [warn]: #0 define <match fluent.**> to capture fluentd logs in top level is deprecated. Use <label @FLUENT_LOG> instead
2022-10-07 16:30:58 +0700 [info]: #0 starting fluentd worker pid=1026746 ppid=1026743 worker=0
2022-10-07 16:30:58 +0700 [info]: #0 following tail of /home/huy/Documents/jbsv-logs/event.log
2022-10-07 16:30:58 +0700 [info]: #0 fluentd worker is now running worker=0
2022-10-07 16:30:58.582555037 +0700 fluent.info: {"pid":1026746,"ppid":1026743,"worker":0,"message":"starting fluentd worker pid=1026746 ppid=1026743 worker=0"}
2022-10-07 16:30:58.582976253 +0700 fluent.info: {"message":"following tail of /home/huy/Documents/jbsv-logs/event.log"}
2022-10-07 16:30:58.583157735 +0700 fluent.info: {"worker":0,"message":"fluentd worker is now running worker=0"}
2022-10-07 16:31:04 +0700 [info]: #0 detected rotation of /home/huy/Documents/jbsv-logs/event.log; waiting 5 seconds
2022-10-07 16:31:04.323800242 +0700 fluent.info: {"message":"detected rotation of /home/huy/Documents/jbsv-logs/event.log; waiting 5 seconds"}
2022-10-07 16:31:04 +0700 [info]: #0 following tail of /home/huy/Documents/jbsv-logs/event.log
2022-10-07 16:31:04.344146840 +0700 fluent.info: {"message":"following tail of /home/huy/Documents/jbsv-logs/event.log"}
2022-10-07 16:31:04 +0700 [warn]: #0 pattern not matched: "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.util.ArrayList<com.jbsv.community.model.integration.navibridge.response.StockListRes>` from Object value (token `JsonToken.START_OBJECT`)"
2022-10-07 16:31:04.344546980 +0700 fluent.warn: {"message":"pattern not matched: \"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.util.ArrayList<com.jbsv.community.model.integration.navibridge.response.StockListRes>` from Object value (token `JsonToken.START_OBJECT`)\""}
2022-10-07 16:31:04 +0700 [warn]: #0 pattern not matched: " at [Source: UNKNOWN; byte offset: #UNKNOWN]"
2022-10-07 16:31:04.344716442 +0700 fluent.warn: {"message":"pattern not matched: \" at [Source: UNKNOWN; byte offset: #UNKNOWN]\""}
2022-10-07 16:31:04 +0700 [warn]: #0 pattern not matched: "    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._convert(ObjectMapper.java:4393)"
2022-10-07 16:31:04.344827597 +0700 fluent.warn: {"message":"pattern not matched: \"    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._convert(ObjectMapper.java:4393)\""}
2022-10-07 16:31:04 +0700 [warn]: #0 pattern not matched: "    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.convertValue(ObjectMapper.java:4334)"
2022-10-07 16:31:04 +0700 [warn]: #0 pattern not matched: "    at com.jbsv.community.handler.kafka.RequestSender.sendKafka(RequestSender.java:62)"
2022-10-07 16:31:04.344889416 +0700 fluent.warn: {"message":"pattern not matched: \"    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.convertValue(ObjectMapper.java:4334)\""}
2022-10-07 16:31:04 +0700 [warn]: #0 pattern not matched: "    at com.jbsv.community.service.integration.NaviBridgeService.getStockList(NaviBridgeService.java:24)"
2022-10-07 16:31:04.344923115 +0700 fluent.warn: {"message":"pattern not matched: \"    at com.jbsv.community.handler.kafka.RequestSender.sendKafka(RequestSender.java:62)\""}
2022-10-07 16:31:04 +0700 [warn]: #0 pattern not matched: "    at com.jbsv.community.service.query.StockListQueryService.getStockList(StockListQueryService.java:35)"
2022-10-07 16:31:04.344951295 +0700 fluent.warn: {"message":"pattern not matched: \"    at com.jbsv.community.service.integration.NaviBridgeService.getStockList(NaviBridgeService.java:24)\""}
2022-10-07 16:31:04 +0700 [warn]: #0 pattern not matched: "    at com.jbsv.community.handler.kafka.RequestHandler.handle(RequestHandler.java:276)"
2022-10-07 16:31:04.345058138 +0700 fluent.warn: {"message":"pattern not matched: \"    at com.jbsv.community.service.query.StockListQueryService.getStockList(StockListQueryService.java:35)\""}
2022-10-07 16:31:04 +0700 [warn]: #0 pattern not matched: "    at com.ftl.common.handlers.BaseRequestHandler.process(BaseRequestHandler.java:80)"
2022-10-07 16:31:04.345123505 +0700 fluent.warn: {"message":"pattern not matched: \"    at com.jbsv.community.handler.kafka.RequestHandler.handle(RequestHandler.java:276)\""}
2022-10-07 16:31:04 +0700 [warn]: #0 pattern not matched: "    at com.ftl.common.handlers.BaseRequestHandler.process(BaseRequestHandler.java:64)"
2022-10-07 16:31:04.345173136 +0700 fluent.warn: {"message":"pattern not matched: \"    at com.ftl.common.handlers.BaseRequestHandler.process(BaseRequestHandler.java:80)\""}
2022-10-07 16:31:04 +0700 [warn]: #0 pattern not matched: "    at com.ftl.common.kafka.KafkaRequestHandler.access$001(KafkaRequestHandler.java:16)"
2022-10-07 16:31:04.345226818 +0700 fluent.warn: {"message":"pattern not matched: \"    at com.ftl.common.handlers.BaseRequestHandler.process(BaseRequestHandler.java:64)\""}
2022-10-07 16:31:04 +0700 [warn]: #0 pattern not matched: "    at com.ftl.common.kafka.KafkaRequestHandler.lambda$init$1(KafkaRequestHandler.java:96)"
2022-10-07 16:31:04.345274890 +0700 fluent.warn: {"message":"pattern not matched: \"    at com.ftl.common.kafka.KafkaRequestHandler.access$001(KafkaRequestHandler.java:16)\""}
2022-10-07 16:31:04 +0700 [warn]: #0 pattern not matched: "    at com.ftl.common.kafka.ThreadedKafkaConsumer$HandleWorker.run(ThreadedKafkaConsumer.java:91)"
2022-10-07 16:31:04.345331055 +0700 fluent.warn: {"message":"pattern not matched: \"    at com.ftl.common.kafka.KafkaRequestHandler.lambda$init$1(KafkaRequestHandler.java:96)\""}
2022-10-07 16:31:04 +0700 [warn]: #0 pattern not matched: "    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)"
2022-10-07 16:31:04.345374105 +0700 fluent.warn: {"message":"pattern not matched: \"    at com.ftl.common.kafka.ThreadedKafkaConsumer$HandleWorker.run(ThreadedKafkaConsumer.java:91)\""}
2022-10-07 16:31:04 +0700 [warn]: #0 pattern not matched: "Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.util.ArrayList<com.jbsv.community.model.integration.navibridge.response.StockListRes>` from Object value (token `JsonToken.START_OBJECT`)"
2022-10-07 16:31:04.345425410 +0700 fluent.warn: {"message":"pattern not matched: \"    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)\""}
2022-10-07 16:31:04 +0700 [warn]: #0 pattern not matched: " at [Source: UNKNOWN; byte offset: #UNKNOWN]"
2022-10-07 16:31:04.345475668 +0700 fluent.warn: {"message":"pattern not matched: \"Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.util.ArrayList<com.jbsv.community.model.integration.navibridge.response.StockListRes>` from Object value (token `JsonToken.START_OBJECT`)\""}
2022-10-07 16:31:04 +0700 [warn]: #0 pattern not matched: "    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException.from(MismatchedInputException.java:59)"
2022-10-07 16:31:04.345518461 +0700 fluent.warn: {"message":"pattern not matched: \" at [Source: UNKNOWN; byte offset: #UNKNOWN]\""}
2022-10-07 16:31:04 +0700 [warn]: #0 pattern not matched: "    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportInputMismatch(DeserializationContext.java:1741)"
2022-10-07 16:31:04.345574224 +0700 fluent.warn: {"message":"pattern not matched: \"    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException.from(MismatchedInputException.java:59)\""}
2022-10-07 16:31:04 +0700 [warn]: #0 pattern not matched: "    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnexpectedToken(DeserializationContext.java:1515)"
2022-10-07 16:31:04.345623282 +0700 fluent.warn: {"message":"pattern not matched: \"    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportInputMismatch(DeserializationContext.java:1741)\""}
2022-10-07 16:31:04 +0700 [warn]: #0 pattern not matched: "    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnexpectedToken(DeserializationContext.java:1462)"
2022-10-07 16:31:04.345673615 +0700 fluent.warn: {"message":"pattern not matched: \"    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnexpectedToken(DeserializationContext.java:1515)\""}
2022-10-07 16:31:04 +0700 [warn]: #0 pattern not matched: "    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.handleNonArray(CollectionDeserializer.java:392)"
2022-10-07 16:31:04.345720938 +0700 fluent.warn: {"message":"pattern not matched: \"    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnexpectedToken(DeserializationContext.java:1462)\""}
2022-10-07 16:31:04 +0700 [warn]: #0 pattern not matched: "    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:252)"
2022-10-07 16:31:04.345766280 +0700 fluent.warn: {"message":"pattern not matched: \"    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.handleNonArray(CollectionDeserializer.java:392)\""}
2022-10-07 16:31:04 +0700 [warn]: #0 pattern not matched: "    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:28)"
2022-10-07 16:31:04.345826349 +0700 fluent.warn: {"message":"pattern not matched: \"    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:252)\""}
2022-10-07 16:31:04 +0700 [warn]: #0 pattern not matched: "    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._convert(ObjectMapper.java:4388)"
2022-10-07 16:31:04.345876839 +0700 fluent.warn: {"message":"pattern not matched: \"    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:28)\""}
2022-10-07 16:31:04 +0700 [warn]: #0 pattern not matched: "    ... 11 common frames omitted"
2022-10-07 16:31:04.345925861 +0700 fluent.warn: {"message":"pattern not matched: \"    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._convert(ObjectMapper.java:4388)\""}
2022-10-07 16:31:04 +0700 [warn]: #0 pattern not matched: ""
2022-10-07 16:31:04.345970630 +0700 fluent.warn: {"message":"pattern not matched: \"    ... 11 common frames omitted\""}
2022-10-07 16:31:04 +0700 [warn]: #0 pattern not matched: "    "
2022-10-07 16:31:04.346033593 +0700 fluent.warn: {"message":"pattern not matched: \"\""}
2022-10-06 02:34:42.784000000 +0700 log.log: {"level":"ERROR","package":"com.ftl.common.handlers.BaseRequestHandler","thread":"Thread-4","message":"exception while handling message"}
2022-10-07 16:31:04.346078129 +0700 fluent.warn: {"message":"pattern not matched: \"    \""}
2022-10-06 02:34:42.784000000 +0700 log.log: {"level":"ERROR","package":"com.ftl.common.handlers.BaseRequestHandler","thread":"Thread-4","message":"exception while handling message"}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RAZwK.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fnrGU.png)

I want to key "message" includes all of Exception line.

Please help me this problem. Thanks a lot!

Comment: We cannot help since you posted sample log excerpts as image. Please post as text.

Comment: Thanks for replying to me. I have changed post as text. Please check again

Comment: Try [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/r8hxqA/1).

Comment: This regex work in regex101 and Fluentular but when I add to td-agent.conf, I still get the same error (fluent.warn: {"message":"pattern not matched: "...}). This error also occurs when I use my regex. Is the problem with td-agent.conf?

Comment: Looks like that.

Comment: @HuyHàQuang: If your issue is not resolved, you might want to look at https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/fluent-plugin-detect-exceptions and https://docs.fluentd.org/parser/multiline plugins.